# new page is loaded - event listen at popup.js sending from content script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I try to make chrome extension which fill the require form fields and continue to next page. Extension has two button one for filling form in the required field and next for submit to continue to next page. Both works perfectly. Now I added new button jump which take target page and do fill - continue until target page is reached.

**manifest.json**

```
{
 "manifest_version":2,

 "name":"My App Name",
 "description":"Description",
 "version":"1.0",
 "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
 },
 "page_action": {
    "default_icon":"icon.png",
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
 },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "notifications",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/",
    "storage"
]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Filler</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css">
        <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="popup"> 
            <button type="button" class="script" id="fill">Fill Page</button>
            <button type="button" class="script" id="continue">Next Page</button>
            <select id="pages" class="dropdown">
                <option value="0">first page</option>
                <option value="1">second page</option>
                <option value="2">third page</option>
                <option value="3">forth page</option>
            </select>
            <button type="button" class="button" id="jump">Jump</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js** (script associated with jump functionality)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('jump').addEventListener('click', jumpPage);
});

function jumpPage() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "jquery-2.1.4.min.js"});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "jump.js"});
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    selectedPage = document.getElementById("pages").value;
    currentPage = (request.pageNum).split(" ")[1];
    if (currentPage) {
        selectedPageInt = parseInt(selectedPage);
        currentPageInt = parseInt(currentPage);
        console.log(selectedPage + " showing something !! " + currentPage);
        if (currentPageInt < selectedPageInt) {
            fillPage();
            nextPage();
        }else {
            alert("Sorry Sir ! I can't take you back !");
        }
    } else {
        alert("Hey Dude ! You are on wrong tab !!");
    }
    if(request.loaded){
        jumpPage();
    }
});
```

content script `jump.js`

```
javascript:
    var pageNumber = document.getElementsByTagName('meta')["pageNum"].getAttribute('content');
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({   pageNum: pageNumber });

    document.onload = function () {
        console.log('onload');
        notifyNewPageLoaded();
    };

    function notifyNewPageLoaded() {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({   loaded: true });
    }
void 0;
```

When jump button is clicked, it fills the required field of the current page and continue to next page. But this process does not repeat again until target page. What i try here is when page loaded to next page, content script should send loaded message true and repeat fill and continue process. This is not the way to do and could not figure out how to notify that next page is loaded to popup.js.

Comment: onload probably never fires because content scripts are injected after the document has already been loaded. Also, use the debugger in devtools, it's the most useful tool in such cases.

Comment: Why are you injecting jQuery when you don't use it?

Comment: You appear to be looking for [`webNavigation`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) events. In particular, [`webNavigation.onCompleted`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onCompleted).